# Xamarin Side Menu Popout Refresh

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am using Xamarin in a UWP project with a MasterDetail main page that includes a list menu that pops out from the left.  The menu is a MenuPage as per `<views:MenuPage>`.
There are two options, 1/ Login 2/ About.
After clicking Login and logging to the application I want to change the menu to show user's menu options but I can't seem to reload the MenuPage's options in any way.  It does not seem to have an refesh.  How do I do this, or do I need to reload the entire main page?

Comment: ```Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();```, after login is successful, seems to work but is this the right way to do this?

Comment: I think this might be causing a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two options, 1/ Login 2/ About. After clicking Login and logging to the application I want to change the menu to show user's menu options but I can't seem to reload the MenuPage's options in any way.

For your requirement, you could change  `menuItems` to `public static ObservableCollection<HomeMenuItem> menuItems` that could access in other page and could response listview change.

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
    public static ObservableCollection<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        menuItems = new ObservableCollection<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Browse, Title="Login" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.About, Title="About" }
        };

        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

        ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];

        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
        };
    }
}
```

Then process menuitems datasouce after click login button.

```
private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MenuPage.menuItems.Insert(0,new HomeMenuItem { Id = MenuItemType.User, Title = "User" });
    MenuPage.menuItems.RemoveAt(1);
    await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu((int)MenuPage.menuItems[0].Id);    
}
```

For better under standing above steps, I upload the code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MasterDetailPageTest), that you could refer to.

Comment: My code looks a bit different but it was the ObservableCollection that's the key.  I have read a bit more about that collection and now my menu works without reloading the whole page.  Instead of trying to replace the menu options I now clear the options and reload with .Add(...).

Comment: I'm just going to give it a go on the Android emulator too and check it still works.

Comment: Yes this worked fine on Android.  I am using entity framework for the first time, which seems very quick and easy.  But forgot that my localhost needs a different address (10.0.2.2) on the android test app!  Also installed HAXM for android which has made the emulator work at a good speed using my desktop's virtualization.  Wow this is great!  I might have speed up debugging if I had remembered to start my database server on the XAMPP control panel though :)

Comment: Now I have to understand using REST api as pure entity framework requires a database and thus username and password which should not be shared...